# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory but echo %JAVA_HOME% is still works

Tags: java, gradle, windows-10, minecraft-forge

Windows 10-

So I was trying to install gradle and set up and stuff (to code a minecraft mod using forge). I got to the point where I just need to check gradle version by doing `Gradle -v` and to end up seeing this

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0_231

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

So I typed `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and it responds with
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0_231`

So I don't really know what went wrong.

Comment: Ist there really a Java binary in this path ?

Comment: The problem may be that there are spaces in the path, i.e. `Program Files`. You could try replacing that with `PROGRA~1`. Also, if you open a [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) and enter the command `where java`, it should output the path to file `java.exe` so that you can check if it really matches your `JAVA_HOME`.